# Translate it in english

Tags: java

```
if(!(nameTextField.getText()).equals("")) {
  validationBoolean = true;
}
else {
  AlertDialog("Name","Customer Name","Please enter name");
  nameTextField.requestFocus();
  validationBoolean = false;
}
```

My teacher gave us this GUI project to do, I understood everything for the most part but this. I know "!" means "not" but I still don't get what this line of code is saying. I was wondering if someone can help me understand this loop.

Comment: this is not a loop. It's an if statement :)

Answer (score 2):

If the name text field's text is not empty (not equal to "") then set the validation boolean = true else, Show an alert dialog, set focus on the name text field and set validation boolean to false

Let's break the first line,

```
if(!(nameTextField.getText()).equals(""))
```

Firstly, get the text from `nameTextField` by using `nameTextField.getText()`
Secondly, Check if it is equal to "", i.e. check if the text is empty.
Finally, invert the condition using `!` so that the `if` block gets executed when the text is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!(nameTextField.getText()).equals(""))
```

If text of the `nameTextField` is not blank ("") then it's valid. Else (if it's blank) it will prompt for Inputs

Answer (score 0):

if your `nameTextField` is empty then your `validationBoolean` will be assigned as true.

if `nameTextField` is not empty then a dialogue will occur with asking **"Name"**, **"Customer Name"** and **"Please enter name"** and then the `validationBoolean` will be assigned as false.

Answer (score 0):

It checks that the value entered in nameTextField is not empty and considers the value valid in this case. Note that any whitespace character passes this simple validation, that's why you usually call trim() beforehand. And FYI, this is not a loop, this is an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

> (nameTextField.getText()).equals("")

This will return true if your textview is empty.
So

> if(!(nameTextField.getText()).equals(""))

this whole line means it is checking if your textview is empty or not. If your textview is not empty, it will return a *false* and the "!" will turn it into true. So if your textview is not empty the if condition will be true and the code insde the if block will execute.

Answer (score 0):

The line `if(!(nameTextField.getText()).equals(""))` says:
if the **text** of the nameTextField **is not empty** then do `validationBoolean = true;`
but if the **text** of the nameTextField **is empty** then create a alert dialog (which will ask for input).